# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'AssesmentModel?'

Tags: flutter, dart

Why do I get below exception when calling getAssesment() method?

I'm trying to set _assesment = data

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'AssesmentModel?'
```

These are my codes, the models (AssesmentModel & AreaModel) and the provider (AssesmentProvider).

AssesmentModel.dart

```
class AssesmentModel {
  late int id;
  late String observerName;
  late String unit;
  late AreaModel area;

  AssesmentModel(
    this.id,
    this.observerName,
    this.unit,
    this.area,
  );

  AssesmentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = int.parse(json['id'].toString());
    observerName = json['observerName'];
    unit = json['unit'];
    area = AreaModel.fromJson(json['area']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'observerName': observerName,
      'unit': unit,
      'area': area.toJson(),
    };
  }
}
```

AssesmentProvider.dart

```
class AssesmentFormProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  AssesmentModel? _assesment;

  AssesmentModel? get assesment => _assesment;

  set assesment(AssesmentModel? assesment) {
    _assesment = assesment;
    notifyListeners();
  }
    
  Future<void> getAssesment() async {
    try {
      // AssesmentModel assesment = await AssesmentService().readJson();
      var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/assesment.json');
      print('the response: ' + response);

      var data = json.decode(response);
      print('assesment in provider');
      print(data);

      _assesment = data;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my AreaModel that relate to AssesmentModel

```
class AreaModel {
  late int id;
  late String name;

  AreaModel(
    this.id,
    this.name,
  );

  AreaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = int.parse(json['id'].toString());
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
    };
  }
}
```

Thank you for the reply. Very apreciated.

Comment: can you include `AreaModel` as well?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh edited

Comment: can you include your json, that will help to test it out.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh {
    "id": 1,
    "observer_name": "Duffy Jhon",
    "unit": "Belawan - Refinery",
    "area": {
        "id": 1,
        "area": "Area-1"
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

What you get from the response is actually a json and you are trying to assign a json to a custom object. You need to create an object from the response data. I see that you already have .fromJson method in your AssestmentModel class so what you can do is simply;

```
    class AssesmentFormProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  AssesmentModel? _assesment;

  AssesmentModel? get assesment => _assesment;

  set assesment(AssesmentModel? assesment) {
    _assesment = assesment;
    notifyListeners();
  }
    
  Future<void> getAssesment() async {
    try {
      // AssesmentModel assesment = await AssesmentService().readJson();
      var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/assesment.json');
      print('the response: ' + response);

      var data = json.decode(response);
      print('assesment in provider');
      print(data);
//you need to create an Assetsment Object and then assign it!
      _assesment = AssetsmentModel.fromJson(data);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

and also you need to modify your .fromJson method to return an Assessment object;

```
            class AssesmentModel {
      late int id;
      late String observerName;
      late String unit;
      late AreaModel area;
    
      AssesmentModel(
        this.id,
        this.observerName,
        this.unit,
        this.area,
      );
    
      AssesmentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AssetsmentModel(
id : int.parse(json['id'].toString()),
        observerName : json['observerName'],
        unit : json['unit'],
        area : AreaModel.fromJson(json['area'])
);
        
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        return {
          'id': id,
          'observerName': observerName,
          'unit': unit,
          'area': area.toJson(),
        };
      }
    }
```

Comment: yeah I forgot the factory type and return in fromJson method, also wrong in _assesment initialization. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few errors like on parser like  on `AreaModel` doesn't have `name`, instead it contains `area`, also some typo errors, go through with this code, and you will get the concept.

```dart
class AreaModel {
  final int id;
  final String area;
  AreaModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.area,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'area': area,
    };
  }

  factory AreaModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return AreaModel(
      id: map['id'],
      area: map['area'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory AreaModel.fromJson(String source) =>
      AreaModel.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class AssesmentModel {
  final int id;
  final String observer_name;
  final String unit;
  final AreaModel area;

  AssesmentModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.observer_name,
    required this.unit,
    required this.area,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'observer_name': observer_name,
      'unit': unit,
      'area': area.toMap(),
    };
  }

  factory AssesmentModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return AssesmentModel(
      id: map['id'],
      observer_name: map['observer_name'],
      unit: map['unit'],
      area: AreaModel.fromMap(map['area']),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory AssesmentModel.fromJson(String source) =>
      AssesmentModel.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

main(List<String> args) {
  final jsonString =
      '{ "id": 1, "observer_name": "Duffy Jhon", "unit": "Belawan - Refinery", "area": { "id": 1, "area": "Area-1" } }';

  final m = AssesmentModel.fromMap(jsonDecode(jsonString));

  print(m.id);
}
```

Comment: yeah I forgot the factory type and return in fromJson method, and there are some typos in my json data properties. thanks.